# Xorg and xrandr detect a connected monitor that doesn't exist

Tags: xorg, xfce, display, xrandr, monitors

I'm on a laptop with no additional monitors connected, but when I run `xrandr -q`, the output lists two connected devices. Xfce's Display settings dialog also shows two monitors, and so does Xorg.0.log.

Here's the `xrandr -q` output:

```
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93    48.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   (omitting many more resolutions)
DP-1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Is this normal? If not, what can I do to remove this imaginary monitor? Restarting the laptop (with no external monitors connected at any point) doesn't change anything.

(My guess it that something about this is causing a weird display problem I have - my login screen starts at the wrong resolution, and afterward the resolution gets corrected but the virtual desktop sizes are wrong.)

Here are related Xorg.0.log lines - DP-1 (the imaginary monitor) does not have an EDID, but it is listed as connected with initial mode 1024x768, and also seems to somehow cause eDP-1 (the actual laptop monitor) to use initial mode 1024x768 instead of 1920x1080; then it gets classified as a keyboard for some reason:

```
[    13.093] (II) modeset(0): Output eDP-1 has no monitor section
[    13.921] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 has no monitor section
[    13.921] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-2 has no monitor section
[    13.921] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-3 has no monitor section
[    13.923] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output eDP-1
[    13.923] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: BOE  Model: 853  Serial#: 0
[    13.923] (II) modeset(0): Year: 2018  Week: 48
[    13.923] (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.4
(skipping a bunch more EDID information for eDP-1)
[    13.924] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output eDP-1
[    13.924] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  141.72  1920 1968 2000 2124  1080 1083 1089 1112 +hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[    13.924] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x119.9  266.50  1920 1944 1960 2000  1080 1081 1084 1111 doublescan +hsync -vsync (133.2 kHz d)
[    13.924] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync (67.2 kHz d)
(skipping a lot more modelines for eDP-1)
[    14.754] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1
[    14.754] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output DP-1
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "848x480"x60.0   33.75  848 864 976 1088  480 486 494 517 +hsync +vsync (31.0 kHz e)
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-2
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-3
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Output eDP-1 connected
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 connected
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-2 disconnected
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-3 disconnected
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Using fuzzy aspect match for initial modes
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Output eDP-1 using initial mode 1024x768 +0+0
[    14.755] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 using initial mode 1024x768 +0+0
(skipping a bunch of lines that seem unrelated - let me know if I should paste the whole thing)
[    15.141] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DP-1 (/dev/input/event10)
[    15.142] (**) DP-1: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    15.142] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'DP-1'
[    15.142] (**) DP-1: always reports core events
[    15.142] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[    15.142] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    15.144] (II) event10 - DP-1: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Pointingstick
[    15.144] (II) event10 - DP-1: device is a pointer
[    15.144] (II) event10 - DP-1: device is a keyboard
[    15.145] (II) event10 - DP-1: device removed
[    15.161] (II) libinput: DP-1: needs a virtual subdevice
[    15.162] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/rc/rc0/input11/event10"
[    15.162] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DP-1" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[    15.162] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    15.162] (**) DP-1: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    15.162] (**) DP-1: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    15.162] (**) DP-1: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    15.164] (II) event10 - DP-1: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Pointingstick
[    15.165] (II) event10 - DP-1: device is a pointer
[    15.165] (II) event10 - DP-1: device is a keyboard
```

Unfortunately my Xorg.0.log.old is from the same day and has the same issues, but I found an Xorg.1.log.old from last year which doesn't. It lists the same eDP-1, but doesn't list any information for DP-1 or classify it as a keyboard or list it as connected, and the initial display mode was 1920x1080 (which is what it should be):

```
    [   942.577] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1
    [   942.577] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-2
    [   942.577] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-3
    [   942.577] (II) modeset(0): Output eDP-1 connected
    [   942.577] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 disconnected
    [   942.577] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-2 disconnected
    [   942.577] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-3 disconnected
    [   942.577] (II) modeset(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
    [   942.577] (II) modeset(0): Output eDP-1 using initial mode 1920x1080 +0+0
```

I'm on a ThinkPad P1 with Xubuntu 20.04 and Xfce 4.14.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a very good answer because the problem seems to have fixed itself after several hours of me messing around and researching solutions but not after I *implemented* a new solution, so I can't really be sure what helped. But  in case someone ends up with a similar problem, here are the only remotely meaningful things I did between a restart that still had the problem and the restart that fixed it:

- I went into the grub command-line and tried the `videoinfo` command (which gave me "error: Secure Boot forbids loading module")
- I went into the BIOS Setup Utility and looked around the Display settings - I left them the same setting they started on ("laptop LCD") but possibly just going into that menu caused something to be re-checked?

So, it's possible that one of those things fixed the problem - might be worth doing them if you have the same issue, anyway.  Or maybe it was something completely unrelated to anything I was doing.

In any case, my Xorg.0.log and xrandr -q are back to showing only a single connected monitor now and everything looks normal, and my weird display problem is gone.

```
[     7.927] (II) modeset(0): Output eDP-1 connected
[     7.927] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 disconnected
[     7.927] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-2 disconnected
[     7.927] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-3 disconnected
[     7.927] (II) modeset(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[     7.927] (II) modeset(0): Output eDP-1 using initial mode 1920x1080 +0+0
```

Additionally: the second time this problem happened, it was fixed when my laptop ran out of battery. (I don't know if a normal restart would've fixed it too that time - I didn't try, since the first time I had this problem a restart only made it worse.)

Comment: Any updates on this one? I’m curious.—Would be nice to know what DP-1 (or DP-2/3) _actually_ are.
Anyway... it looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

From [ArchWiki: xrandr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr#Disabling_phantom_monitor):

> In some cases, a non-existent monitor may be detected by the system.
> To disable it, find the name of the phantom output, e.g. VGA1, and
> turn it off with
>
> ```
> $ xrandr --output VGA1 --off
> ```
>
> To make this permanent, add the following to an entry in
> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/:
>
> ```
> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf
> Section "Monitor"
>     Identifier "VGA1"
>     Option "Ignore" "true"
> EndSection
> ```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have done anything - I ran `xrandr --output DP-1 --off` but the output of `xrandr -q` still says `DP-1 connected` afterward.

Comment: @weronika Yes, `connected` is the detection status. And obviously something gets inadequately detected.—But the practical issues should be gone, as the window manager does not try to display anything there any more.